# Using My.Settings Variables within Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, my.settings

I have 2 Settings in my.settings within my vb.net Project called

my.settings.company
my.settings.tel

and I would like these to be displayed at the top of my Crystal Report.

I tried using the Database Expert within my report and added the .NET Object "My.Settings" to the Report and then dragged the company and tel variables to my report, however this doesn't work at all.

Any help ???

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and probably the right way is to define parameters and to set their values from your application

Comment: I can define Parameters in Crystal however what Code do I need to SET this in a Report Object ObjRpt ??

Comment: I have Created Parameter field in Crystal Report, and used the below code to attempt to pass a STRING to this field, but when I run the Program it Still comes up and asks me to Enter a value for the Parameter.

Comment: Seems like the code was truncated. What kind of program is this ? Before to go further and change your project try to make the report. There are plenty of free viewers around. Install one and use it to run the report. Once you are sure you like what you see change your project. I recommend R-Tag Community edition because it is free and easy to use - http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx. There are other free tools on the market if you don't like this one.

Comment: Of course you can use Crystal designer to run the report , but it will use a different engine. Your project will use Crystal runtime for .NET.